# Matrix multiplication-style addition in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a row vector `a` and a column vector `b` in numpy. If I was to do matrix multiplication on the two vectors, I would obtain a matrix `m` where `m[i,j] = a[i]b[j]`. I was wondering if there was a simple way of performing this style of operation for addition - i.e, obtaining  a matrix `n` where `n[i,j] = a[i] + b[j]`. Is there a built-in method for performing something like this?

Comment: Have you read about `numpy` `broadcasting` yet?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: FYI, `m[i,j] = a[i]b[j]` is *not* matrix multiplication.

Comment: @QuangHoang, it's actually `outer product`.  Matrix product of a (n,1) with (1,m) does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)?

```
import numpy as np    

x1 = np.arange(3).reshape((3, 1))
x2 = np.arange(3).reshape((1, 3))
result = np.add(x1, x2)

print(x1, '\n')
print(x2, '\n')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]] 

[[0 1 2]] 

[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

Comment: `+` works fine. You don't need to invoke the ufunc explicitly.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica true that!

Answer (score 1):

A compact way of expanding a (n,) array to (n,1) is with the `np.newaxis` or `None` indexing:

```
In [30]: a = np.arange(1,5); b = np.arange(1,4)*10                                             
In [31]: a,b                                                                                   
Out[31]: (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([10, 20, 30]))
In [32]: a[:,None]+b                                                                           
Out[32]: 
array([[11, 21, 31],
       [12, 22, 32],
       [13, 23, 33],
       [14, 24, 34]])
```

where:

```
In [33]: a[:,None]                                                                             
Out[33]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

The `broadcasting` process is:

```
(m,1), (n,) => (m,1),(1,n) => (m,n)
```

The `ufunc` version of `+` is `np.add`, and as such it has an `outer` method:

```
In [35]: np.add.outer(a,b)                                                                     
Out[35]: 
array([[11, 21, 31],
       [12, 22, 32],
       [13, 23, 33],
       [14, 24, 34]])
```

`np.outer(a,b)` and `np.multiply.outer(a,b)` and `a[:,None]*b` are equivalent `outer product` expressions.